# c# - Form components not updating when using sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

Good day all

This is a piece of code which is part of a small lan chat (expermentation) program, however when sending messages to this, the server, it is recieved (as per debugging I can see the results) but the gui fails to update (gui meaning richedit and label)

When I click send, the receiveText(string IP) is called, which executes and awaits for a connection, when it recieves a connetion, it handles as it should but,

**Problem :**

*Only after this method (and related) have been executed, the gui updates*, so when this method finishes, and its calling method finishes (button_click) too, only then while the program is waiting for input, they richedit displays the messages and the label is updated

*I tried w/ and w/o the while loops, both have the same result*

```
 private void recieveText(string _IPADDRESS)
        {
            //initialise multicast group and bind to interface
            Socket _listener_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _PORT);
            _listener_socket.Bind(ipep);
            IPAddress localip = IPAddress.Parse("224.5.6.7");
            _listener_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(localip, IPAddress.Any));

            //recieve data to multicast group
            //while (true)
            //{
            //while (_listener_socket.Connected)
            //{
                label1.Text = "listening...";
                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                _listener_socket.Receive(b);
                label1.Text = "message recieved";
                redBox.AppendText("\n---------------------------------\n New Message :\n");

                char[] chars = new char[b.Length / sizeof(char)];
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(b, 0, chars, 0, b.Length);

                string t = new string(chars).Trim();
                redBox.AppendText(t);
                redBox.AppendText("\n----------------------------------\n\n");
            //}
            //}
        }
```

Comment: That's the right behaviour, the UI updates on the main thread, so if you're blocking it the UI does not update. Use a separated thread for the comms or use asynchronous methods.

Comment: @Gusman thanks, I just tried using a invoke, I thought a seperate thread my do the trick, could you possibly elaborate on asychronus methods, would appreciate it

Comment: Take a look at Socket.BeginReceive, Socket.EndReceive, Socket.BeginSend, Socket,EndSend, Socket.ReceiveAsync and Socket.SendAsync. First four methods are for plain direct code, the other two are for async api.

Comment: @Gusman please post your thread suggestion with invoke updates for controls, this is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see updates and don't block the main thread you must receive the data in a separated thread.

Here is an example:

```
    private void recieveText(string _IPADDRESS)
    {
        //initialise multicast group and bind to interface
        Socket _listener_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _PORT);
        _listener_socket.Bind(ipep);
        IPAddress localip = IPAddress.Parse("224.5.6.7");
        _listener_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(localip, IPAddress.Any));

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {
            BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { label1.Text = "listening..."; }));

            while (_listener_socket.Connected)
            {

                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                _listener_socket.Receive(b);

                char[] chars = new char[b.Length / sizeof(char)];
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(b, 0, chars, 0, b.Length);

                string t = new string(chars).Trim();

                BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    label1.Text = "message recieved";
                    redBox.AppendText("\n---------------------------------\n New Message :\n");
                    redBox.AppendText(t);
                    redBox.AppendText("\n----------------------------------\n\n");
                }));
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the example using different threads as you requested BUT this is not the best way to do it, as I said in my comment the right way is to use the asynchronous methods, the old ones (BeginXXX/EndXXX) or the new async ones (XXXAsync).